# Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 preseed won't mount NFS volume during install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I have a preseed installation, which runs a script on its late_command. The preseed itself works fine, the script - too. I want to mount NFS volume with this script and get the packages from there. The directories are all in place beforehand, the nfs-common package is installed as well, /etc/hosts - too. However, this line fails:
`mount -t nfs -o ro server:/nfs/volume /nfs`. It fails even if I supply the IP address. I went in tty2 during the installation and attempted to simulate this. What I got was `rpc.statd` not running. I tried to start it, but it won't. I could mount the volume manually after the installation. Seems to me that something prevents the rpc.statd from running.

Please note - I can use the same preseed file and late_command script with external or internal http mirror. There is no question of their syntax or functioning state. But I have to use it with local NFS mirror and I don't see why it is not working.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you disable locking. Try to mount with `mount -t nfs -o ro,nolock server:/nfs/volume /nfs`